# frameset in html is not my desired result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to split the web page into 3 cols ,3 rows , but all the content is display in one page.
Can I display it in more than one page , when I scrolling the top frameset's scrollbar but not the third rows's scrollbar?

the html code is :

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Monitor Task</title>
    </head>
    <frameset style="overflow: scroll;" rows="40%,40%,20%">
        <frameset cols="40%,40%,40%">
            <frame name="test" src="test.html">
                <frame name="test" src="test.html">
                    <frame name="test" src="test.html">
        </frameset>
        <frameset cols="40%,40%,40%">
            <frame name="test" src="test.html">
                <frame name="test" src="test.html">
                    <frame name="test" src="test.html">
        </frameset>
        <frameset cols="40%,40%,40%">
            <frame name="test" src="test.html">
                <frame name="test" src="test.html">
                    <frame name="test" src="test.html">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

the result is
[image]

The effect of the red rectangle is not what I want ,

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean with "all the content is display in one page." and "Can I display it in more than one page , and scrolling?"

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard I mean, when the top frameset's right scrollbar scrolling,and the third rows also can display all the content,not display one part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give this attribute `frameborder="0"` and `noresize` for all the `frame` tags.

```
<frame name="test" src="test.html" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" />
```

And please close all the `frame` tags.

Comment: I have tried,but It doen't work,the third row also has the scroll and not display in next page.

Comment: Try this: `scrolling="no"` or `scrolling="auto"`. And lemme know the result! @lanyun.

Comment: The scrolling="auto" never change the result. The scrolling="no" change the result, the third rows has no scrollbar,but still also show one part.